# PHPMyAdmin Error Code: 500, Internal Server Error on Cloud Google Platform

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I just deployed a new VM instance on GCP for Wordpress. Now I'm trying to access PHPMyAdmin, I am able to log-in but when I try to select a database, try to create a new table, it only returns the error.

I tried making a new instance and deployment, but it still returns the same error. I'm wondering if there's any configuration I need to do before using phpmyadmin

Comment: Checking my error.log in Apache2, it shows this

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unk>